# Ubuntu: Firefox First Start problems

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-18.04

How to reset Firefox in Ubuntu? 
When first started Firefox asks for some privacy settings but when internet connection is broken at that time of first run no settings can be done obviously. So when the connection is ok and you start Firefox the second time no page with settings is shown. How to reset Firefox and force it to start with that page?

Answer (score 0):

All settings can be found in the Options page, accessible with a left-click on the "hamburger" menu icon in the top right corner of the main Firefox window.

Click on Options, and customize your Firefox the way you like.

Alternatively, press the Alt key on your keyboard, to show the menu bar, go to Edit / Preferences (or Options, depending on the Linux distro you're running), and you'll achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know that it is possible to do so. But on the first run page you can access all the components step by step and also information on privacy is provided right away. So I really would like to do the first run for the Firefox again. Is it possible?

Comment: Type "about:config" in the address bar and press Enter, then search for "first", and find an entry called "datareporting.policy.firstRunURL". The URL that's in the chain is the one you want. Highlight it, copy-paste if in your address bar, go there, and do what you have to do in terms of privacy settings.